# MySql query help : joints with sums and counts

Tags: mysql, join

I have this database structure:

```
TBL_A  |  TBL_B  |  TBL_C  |  TBL_D  | TBL_E
-------+---------+---------+---------+----------
id     | id_tbla | id_tbla | id_tbla | id
name   | id_user | id_user | id_user | name_tbla
...    | is_bool |         | weight  | id_user
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.name, 
    b.is_bool,
    count(c.id_user) AS nb_views, 
    sum(d.weight) AS total_weight,
    count(distinct e.id_user) AS distinct_users,
FROM TBL_A AS a 
LEFT JOIN (TBL_B AS b) on (b.id_tbla = a.id)
LEFT JOIN (TBL_C AS c) on (c.id_tbla = a.id)
LEFT JOIN (TBL_D AS d) on (d.id_tbla = a.id)
LEFT JOIN (TBL_E AS e) on (e.name_tbla = a.name)
where a.id = 1 and e.id_user = 1
```

The query is performed but the results (nb_views, total_weight, distinct_users) are wrong. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compute too many aggregates in one query.

> *Enita non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem*
>
> (Latin, "entities are not to be multiplied beyond necessity")

Your tables B, C, D, and E are produced [Cartesian Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) against each other.  Suppose the 
given row in A matches:

- 3 rows in B
- 6 rows in C
- 4 rows in D
- 1 row in E

The total number of rows in the result is 3 * 6 * 4 * 1 = 72 rows.  So your `count(c.id_user)` is 12 times what it should be, your `sum(d.weight)` is 18 times what it should be, etc.

The simplest remedy is to compute each of these aggregates in a separate query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COALESCE(b.is_bool, FALSE) AS is_bool
FROM TBL_A AS a LEFT JOIN TBL_B AS b ON (b.id_tbla = a.id)
WHERE a.id = 1;

SELECT a.id, COUNT(c.id_user) AS nb_views
FROM TBL_A AS a LEFT JOIN TBL_C AS c ON (c.id_tbla = a.id)
WHERE a.id = 1;

SELECT a.id, SUM(d.weight) AS total_weight,
FROM TBL_A AS a LEFT JOIN TBL_D AS d ON (d.id_tbla = a.id)
WHERE a.id = 1;

SELECT a.id, COUNT(DISTINCT e.id_user) AS distinct_users,
FROM TBL_A AS a LEFT JOIN TBL_E AS e 
  ON (e.name_tbla = a.name AND e.id_user = 1)
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Comment: Perfect! You even helped me understand the numbers I got from the request. I'll do 4 requests then! So much for trying to do everything at once for a couple of hours... :)